# Make multiple calls asterisk ari python

Tags: python-3.x, asterisk

I wrote a script on python 3 that makes only one call, if the caller answered, then we play the melody and hang up. I use ari asterisk. How can this be done for only a few numbers?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import sys
import websocket
import requests
import time


class ARIInterface(object):
    def __init__(self, server_addr, username, password):
        self._req_base = "http://%s:8088/ari/" % server_addr
        self._username = username
        self._password = password

    def answer_call(self, channel_id):
        req_str = self._req_base + "channels/%s/answer" % channel_id
        self._send_post_request(req_str)

    def play_sound(self, channel_id, sound_name):
        req_str = self._req_base + ("channels/%s/play?media=sound:%s" % (channel_id, sound_name))
        self._send_post_request(req_str)

    def cr_channel(self, number):
        req_str = self._req_base + ("channels/create?endpoint=SIP/25002/%s&app=hello" % (number))
        self._send_post_request(req_str)

    def dial_channel(self, channel_id):
        req_str = self._req_base + ("channels/%s/dial?timeout=30" % (channel_id))
        self._send_post_request(req_str)

    def del_channel(self, channel_id):
        req_str = self._req_base + ("channels/%s" % (channel_id))
        self._send_delete_request(req_str)

    def _send_post_request(self, req_str):
        r = requests.post(req_str, auth=(self._username, self._password))

    def _send_delete_request(self, req_str):
        r = requests.delete(req_str, auth=(self._username, self._password))


class ARIApp(object):
    def __init__(self, server_addr):
        app_name = 'hello'
        username = 'ari-user'
        password = 'ari-ewsd-135'
        url = "ws://%s:8088/ari/events?app=%s&api_key=%s:%s" % (server_addr, app_name, username, password)

        ari = ARIInterface(server_addr, username, password)
        ws = websocket.create_connection(url)

        numbers = [21018, 35000]

        ari.cr_channel('21018')

        channel_id = json.loads(ws.recv())['channel']['id']

        ari.dial_channel(channel_id)

        try:
            for event_str in iter(lambda: ws.recv(), None):
                event_json = json.loads(event_str)
                json.dump(event_json, sys.stdout, indent=2, sort_keys=True,
                          separators=(',', ': '))
                print("\n\nWebsocket event***************************************************\n")

                try:
                    if event_json['dialstatus'] == 'ANSWER':
                        peer_id = event_json['peer']['id']
                        ari.play_sound(peer_id, 'hello-world')
                        time.sleep(2)
                        ari.del_channel(peer_id)
                except:
                    pass

        except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
            print("Websocket connection closed")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interrupt")
        finally:
            if ws:
                ws.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ARIApp('localhost')
```

I tried to change the Ariapp class as follows:

```
class ARIApp(object):
    def __init__(self, server_addr):
        app_name = 'hello'
        username = 'ari-user'
        password = 'ari-ewsd-135'
        url = "ws://%s:8088/ari/events?app=%s&api_key=%s:%s" % (server_addr, app_name, username, password)

        ari = ARIInterface(server_addr, username, password)
        ws = websocket.create_connection(url)

        numbers = [21018, 35000]
        
        for number in numbers:          

            ari.cr_channel(number)

            channel_id = json.loads(ws.recv())['channel']['id']

            ari.dial_channel(channel_id)

        try:
            for event_str in iter(lambda: ws.recv(), None):
                event_json = json.loads(event_str)
                json.dump(event_json, sys.stdout, indent=2, sort_keys=True,
                          separators=(',', ': '))
                print("\n\nWebsocket event***************************************************\n")

                try:
                    if event_json['dialstatus'] == 'ANSWER':
                        peer_id = event_json['peer']['id']
                        ari.play_sound(peer_id, 'hello-world')
                        time.sleep(2)
                        ari.del_channel(peer_id)
                except:
                    pass

        except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
            print("Websocket connection closed")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interrupt")
        finally:
            if ws:
                ws.close()
```

Comment: I wanted to fix the code, but the forum won't let me do it.

Comment: you need more reputation and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many channels as you want. There is no limit

You should use Originate AMI call or call files if you want independent channels

Comment: Is it really impossible to implement this on an ami?

Comment: What? AMI has action Originate.

Comment: Indeed, I can make one call without any problems. It is not possible to make exactly several calls.

Comment: Do it twice? What prevent you from doing that?

Comment: I apologize for not responding for a long time. I made a typo at the top, I meant ARI.
Is it possible to make multiple calls using the API?